# Get the newest rows for each foreign key ID

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I don't want to aggregate any columns.  I just want the newest row for each foreign key in a table.

I've tried grouping.

```
Model.query.order_by(Model.created_at.desc()).group_by(Model.foreign_key_id).all()
# column "model.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause
```

And I've tried distinct.

```
Model.query.order_by(Model.created_at.desc()).distinct(Model.foreign_key_id).all()
# SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group), and for PostgreSQL you can use `DISTINCT ON`, as in your second example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (foreign_key_id) * FROM model ORDER BY foreign_key_id, created_at DESC;
```

In your attempt, you were missing the `DISTINCT ON` column in your `ORDER BY` list, so all you had to do was:

```
Model.query.order_by(Model.foreign_key_id, Model.created_at.desc()).distinct(Model.foreign_key_id)
```

Comment: Is this solution faster than the one I posted?

Comment: @ColtonAllen In general, yes, slightly. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/341730) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to left join an aliased model to itself (with a special join condition).  Then filter out the rows that do not have an `id`.

```
model = Model
aliased = aliased(Model)
query = model.query.outerjoin(aliased, and_(
    aliased.primary_id == model.primary_id,
    aliased.created_at > model.created_at))
query = query.filter(aliased.id.is_(None))
```